# RightBarItem in TabViewController not firing unless the textView inside the child view is being edited

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I have a TabViewController with 3 children (2 TableViewControllers and one ViewController with a Label and TextView)

I have added a RightBarButtonItem to the Navigation, but the problem is that the Bar Button is not firing..

After some experiments I noticed that only when the selected view is the ViewController, and only if the TextView is being edited, the Bar Button fires.
If the TextView is done editing, or if the selected view is one of the TableViewControllers, the Bar Button does not fire

Here is my TabViewController class

```
class InfoTabViewController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

var index: Int?
var rightBarItem: UIBarButtonItem?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // MARK: RightBarButtonItem
    rightBarItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    rightBarItem!.style = .Plain
    rightBarItem!.action = #selector(self.rightBarItemSelected)
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightBarItem


    self.delegate = self
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    // MARK: RightBarButtonItem
    editRightBarItem()
}

//Useless, fires before the tabbar item is selected not after... go to TabBarController instead
override func tabBar(tabBar: UITabBar, didSelectItem item: UITabBarItem) {
    //print(self.selectedViewController?.title)
}

// UITabBarControllerDelegate fires after the tabbar item is selected, good one
func tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController) {
    editRightBarItem()
}

// MARK: RightBarButtonItem
func editRightBarItem() {
    if let title = self.selectedViewController?.title {
        switch title {
            case "Tab Investigations":
                rightBarItem!.title = "Add"

                //rightBarItem!.enabled = true
                break
            case "Tab Treatment":
                rightBarItem!.title = "Add"
                //rightBarItem!.enabled = true
                break
            case "Tab Images":
                rightBarItem!.title = "Add"
                //rightBarItem!.enabled = true
                break
            case "Tab Notes":
                rightBarItem!.title = "Save"
                //rightBarItem!.enabled = true
                break
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}

// MARK: RightBarButtonItem
func rightBarItemSelected() {
    print("right bar item selected")
    if let title = self.selectedViewController?.title {
        print(title)
        switch title {
        case "Tab Investigations":
            getInput(title, title: "New Test", message: "Insert Name and Value")
            break
        case "Tab Treatment":
            getInput(title, title: "New Drug", message: "Insert Name and Dose")
            break
        case "Tab Images":
            // do something
            break
        case "Tab Notes":
            let view = self.viewControllers![0] as! NotesViewController
            Patient.lstPatients[index!].history = view.textboxNotes.text
            view.textboxNotes.endEditing(true)
            //getInput("Add new test", message: "Insert name and value", viewTitle: self.selectedViewController!.title!)
            break
        default:
            break
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reason why button not fire - you forgot to set `target`. Here is some words from documentation:

> `weak var target: AnyObject? { get set }`
>
> The object that
>   receives an action when the item is selected. If nil, the action
>   message is passed up the responder chain where it may be handled by
>   any object implementing a method corresponding to the selector held by
>   the action property. The default value is nil.

So, try to add

```
rightBarItem.target = self
```

or use more wide initializer

```
rightBarItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Add", style: .Plain, target: self, action: #selector(self.rightBarItemSelected))
```

Comment: This is perfect answer,thanx